# How to delete the QueryCache

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to update the QueryCache.
I dont know how to delete the QueryCache.

```
$book = Book::findFirst(
  array("id = 1",
  ’cache’ => array( 
    ’key’ =>’book_id_1’,
    ’lifetime’ => 3600
  )
)

if($shop->updated_at > $book->updated_at)
{
  $book->cache->delete(’book_id_1’); // <- of course dont work...
//-----------------------------------------------------//
}
```

Please tell me  delete or update the QueryCache...

Answer (score 0):

use the following code, you will have to retrieve the key and then call delete using the key,

```
$keys = $cache->queryKeys('book_id_1');
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $cache->delete($key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! sorry ...Where '$cache' came?